# "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field devUserId on serializer AssetSerializer. Original exception text was: 'devUserId'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    googleId = models.CharField(max_length=512, primary_key=True, default='')
    imageURL = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    #phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex=r"^+?1?\d{8,15}$")
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    email1 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=False)
    email2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    planId = models.ForeignKey('primal_user.Plans',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default="Free")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    accountCreationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    assetsDownloaded = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    assetsPurchased = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Asset(models.Model):
    assetId = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    devUserId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    keywordId = models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assetName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    features = models.TextField(blank=True)
    uploadedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    typeId = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    paidStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=False)
    downloadCount = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class UserAsset(APIView):
    def get(self,request,devUserId):
        try:
            user = Asset.objects.filter(devUserId=devUserId).values()
            serializer = AssetSerializer(user, many= True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Asset.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

[KeyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ammVv.png)

I am a beginner in Django, so am unable to figure out what the issue is. I tried looking for solutions to similar questions but could not resolve the issue. I was getting attribute error, then it was resolved after I entered many=True in AssetSerializer but now I am stuck with this KeyError. A while trying to figure out the error, I noticed that this error is thrown while executing serializer.data. Thank You for any help possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, just a small change is needed in syntax.

**Instead of:**

```py
user = Asset.objects.filter(devUserId=devUserId).values()
```

**Write:**

```py
user = Asset.objects.filter(devUserId=devUserId)
```

And that should solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

> try with `user = Asset.objects.values('fieldnamehere').filter(devUserId=devUserId)`